# Markdown syntax: From document A I want to link to a part of document B

Tags: markdown

I know how to link from document A to document B. 
In A:

```
[B](path/to/B.md)
```

I also know how to link from document A to a part of document A:
In A:

```
[Header In A](#header-name)
```

I would like to have both and from A link to a part of document B. Something like:
In A:

```
[Header in B](/path/to/B.md#header-name)     <==== doesn't work
```

**Note**: I'm not interested in writing html. I would like to know if there is anyway to achieve it in Markdown syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What does Markdown output for your third example? Which Markdown processor are you using?

Comment: My bad. I tested it again. It works on Github. Example: https://github.com/tinnou/markdown/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

On Github it actually works. I guess I was too lazy to test it correctly. Thanks @Chris

`[Header in B](path/to/B.md#header-name)`

Example here:
https://github.com/tinnou/markdown/blob/master/README.md